# How to enable a date range in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

How can we create a date range using bootstrap date picker.
Example: I have dates like startdate:25/06/2013 and endDate:24/02/2014 how to disable past date before startDate and future date after endDate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an specific plugin wich supports date ranges, like [Date Range Picker for Twitter Bootstrap](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker).